# What are 3 types of Ring CT transactions?

Tags: ringct

In monero, there are [three types of RingCT transactions](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/c6f26ecae280fa231ccc51e125bbf556ed6bbf9d/src/ringct/rctTypes.h#L167):

```
enum {
  RCTTypeNull = 0,
  RCTTypeFull = 1,
  RCTTypeSimple = 2,
};
```

They can be observed in https://xmrchain.net/

But it's not clear what differences there are among the three types, and why there are three types at all. Why not only one type?

Answer (score 10):

- `Null` is used for coinbase transactions. There are no inputs to sign, so no signatures can be provided. If a miner uses this mode (as opposed to `tx.version == 1`) then the coinbase output can be used as a dummy input in *any* rct transaction (AFAIK, primarily due to how it is stored in a database).
- `Simple` is currently used when a transaction has multiple inputs. There is a [LSAG signature](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/027.pdf) for each input. Each LSAG is smaller in size than a `tx.version == 1` signature, so there is still some space savings over the original signature method.
- `Full` is used when the transaction has a single input. The [MRL-005](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf) discusses this mode in the MLSAG section - it is a signature over all inputs. This allows for more space savings over `Simple` mode when there are multiple inputs. However, `Full` mode requires that all "real" inputs be at the same offset within the ring, and therefore has not been enabled primarily due to privacy concerns (along with one subtle implementation detail).

**Edit** - Some clarification:

- `Full` mode *is* used, but only when a transaction has 1 input.
- `Simple` mode is actually a collection of MLSAG signatures, each of which links the commitment to zero with the key image / previous output address.

Comment: As a slight update, MLSAGs were replaced with Borromean signatures recently.

Comment: Borromean signatures are used for the range proofs, which is separate from verifying the signatures to prior transaction outputs.

Comment: I've posted to [MRL repo](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/issues/6) about my understanding of how `Simple` works, and I'm confused here why `Full` is still used in the case of only one input; wouldn't both `Simple` and `Full` be practically the same?

Another side question (maybe I should make a separate SE post): is Borromean only used for the rangeproof but not for the input rings? It seems to be able to reduce the signature size by a few tens of bytes.

Comment: The "one signature for all" scheme is a tad smaller, so gets used for one input, where it doesn't have a drawback.

Comment: And to answer the other question - Borromean is only used for the range proof. MLSAG is used for the inputs / commitments. That mode ensures that the commitment to zero is at the same index in the ring as the signature for the input, without revealing the ring position.